# Intellij wont show Maven archetype, even though the files are in local repository

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, maven-archetype, openjfx

Ive been trying to set up JavaFX with Maven nearly the whole day.

Although it seems to be working (I could run the demo and there were no errors), I am still puzzled as to why I cant find the ["org.openjfx:..." Archetypes in the "new Project window"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUCeR.png)

[image]

even thought the files exist inside my [local Maven repository.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHUiJ.png)

[image]

I am using Maven 3.6.3 and Intellij 2021.2.2

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: ok, I will remove the picture with the code. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Removing the image is only part of it. Much more important is that you add the relevant information as formatted text. Take some time to read the links I shared, and edit your question accordingly. Also, make sure to read [ask] if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I'll keep code formatting in my mind for future Questions. But except for that the only problem I can see is that I did not tell what my Maven, Intellij and other component versions are.

Comment: I think, by default, [intellij only knows about its internal present maven archetypes, not custom maven archetypes](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009667139/comments/360002485460).  You could try [the maven archetype catalogs plugin for intellij](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965-maven-archetype-catalogs?_ga=2.7505457.224375986.1632760355-660839124.1632428660) which allows you to use custom archetype catalogs.  I have never used it.  Or you could construct the artefacts from the command line.  Or perhaps easier, import the projects from a github link

Comment: That's basically what I did. I first tried to add the archetype via the "new Project" window. After that didn't work, i fetched the files directly via GitHub link. And finally I added the correct groupId, artifactId and version inside my pom.xml file, which got it to work. But still it doesn't show up on "new Project", so for future projects I would have to fetch the file every time which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I did not try it but I think the archetype catalog plug-in I linked, if correctly configured, would allow to create projects based on the openjfx archetypes directly from the ide rather than via the command line as documented in the readme files [root](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes) and [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes/tree/master/javafx-archetype-fxml) for the archetypes.  If it were me I wouldn’t use archetypes for a new project, I would use the idea [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html)

Comment: Thank you for the Info, creating a JavaFX project results in exactly what I had wanted from the beginning.